# User's photo variable and store it in session for access on every page in Grails

Tags: session, variables, grails

I simply need to know how can I store users Photo variable in session
so I can access it anywhere in the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup in original controller:

```
session.photo = photoVariable
```

Get in another controlelr:

```
session.photo
```

Get access from GSP:

```
${session.photo}
```

See http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/guide/theWebLayer.html#controllersAndScopes

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answers...
just wondering... Is there any way I can set session photo in gsp file?

Comment: gsp? Why you can't set it in contoller?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use Igor's answer and store your photo in the session. You could Base64 encode it like this:

```
 data:${user.photoMimeType};base64,${user.photo}
```

where photoMimeType is usually "image/jpeg" or "image/png" and the user.photo is stored in your database as Base64.encode(image bytes)

in your view you could then use

```
<img src="${session.photo}"/>
```

where the photo would be inlined in your html. The down side to this solution is, that every html has the image inlined, and this is not good for caching.

Alternative solution is:

In your login controller:

```
 session.photoUrl = g.createLink(controller: 'user', action: 'img', id: user.id)
```

In your gsp:

```
 <img src="${session.photoUrl}"
```

And in your user controller:

```
def img = {
    def user = User.get(params.id)
    if(user) {
        response.setContentType(user.imageMimeType)
        response.outputStream << user.imageData
    } else {
        log.debug "not found"
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND)
    }
}
```

Hope this is a solution you can use

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get the profile picture working on everywhere on the app through session with the help of set tag. http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Tags/set.html
Now the issue I am facing is when i change the session user its profile picture changes all right but its thumbnail photo doesn't work unless you refresh the page once.

could anyone explian this please.
Appreciate your help.
Thanks

Could anyone explain this profile image function/action

```
def profilePhoto = {
    response.setContentType('image/jpeg')
    response.setHeader('Cache-control', 'no-cache')
    def userId = session.selectedUser.id
    if(params.userId){
      userId = params.userId
    }
    if(params?.id != null && !(params?.id.empty)){
      params.maxWidth?: 190.00
      params.maxHeight?: 190.00
      response.outputStream << imageProxyService.loadThumbnailImage(params.id, securityService.passwordEncoder(userId.toString()))
    }
  }
```